# Production for multiplant firm?

Tags: microeconomics, production-function

A multi-plant firm will never produce at a plant with an increasing marginal cost when they own another plant with a decreasing marginal cost. Is this true?

My reasoning behind this is that firms would want to minimize their cost so they would prefer to produce at a plant with a decreasing marginal cost.

Comment: Does decreasing marginal cost imply that it is smaller than the increasing marginal cost? If not, I don't understand your reasoning. If yes, why?

Comment: @Giskard Wouldn't the cost of the additional unit produced be cheaper for the plant with the decreasing marginal cost? The total cost will therefore be lower if the firm owner produce from the plant with decreasing marginal cost.

Comment: Would the cost of the additional unit produced be cheaper for the plant with the decreasing marginal cost? Why?

Comment: The trick is that, though at a cursory glance it seems that if the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing in $n$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = -\infty$ is true, this is not the case. As a counterpoint: one can (probably) think of several sequences where $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$. Perhaps it is also possible that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 1$?

Comment: @Giskard Thank you for your reply. I don't really understand your discussion in limit terms, but let me see if I can get this correct in numbers term. It can be possible that the cost of producing an additional unit in the plant with increasing marginal cost is 10 dollars but the cost of producing an additional unit in the plant with decreasing marginal cost is 20 dollars. A firm would therefore would choose to continue to produce in the plant with increasing marginal cost because the cost of an additional unit is still cheaper there. Is this the correct intuition?

Comment: Yes, very good.

Comment: Looking at your list of questions: you are asking about 2SLS but you do not understand limit terms? That seems like a peculiar economics program.